# @nuxtjs/vuetify no style applied

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have an issue using vuetify in a Nuxt project, I've followed the documentation saying you just need to install the `@nuxtjs/vuetify` dependency to your project and add one line in the `buildModules` section of your `nuxt.config.js` file. The components are working fine but I don't see any css style on them, what's wrong ?

[image: nuxt vuetify no css]

Here is my nuxt.config.js file

```
   export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'mounir-ssr-diabete',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', {}],
  ],

  router: {},

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    [
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',
      {
        config: {
          apiKey: 'AIzaSyD_wgrl3S3RjpgwaEP2bDLpLDnIQz2C2Vc',
          authDomain: 'mounir-ssr.firebaseapp.com',
          projectId: 'mounir-ssr',
          storageBucket: 'mounir-ssr.appspot.com',
          messagingSenderId: '26338888590',
          appId: '1:26338888590:web:be1893a374f3abc10cb2df',
          measurementId: 'G-Y7YHDQDLM8',
        },
        services: {
          auth: {
            persistence: 'local', // default
            initialize: {
              onAuthStateChangedAction: 'onAuthStateChangedAction',
              subscribeManually: false,
            },
            ssr: false,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {},

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `vuetify` theme information in the `nuxt.config.js` file alongside `axios` and `build`. like this ..

```
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify",
  ],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {},
    
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ["~/assets/variables.scss"],
    theme: {
      light: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

ask me if it is not clear for you.

Comment: It is clear but what if I don't want to customize the it ? Can I simply add vuetify as part of modules empty ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case, using `v-app` in the template code solved it (e.g., just using `v-banner` didn't include the Vuetify styles, but when adding `v-app` around it, the styles magically appeared). Above answer with the Nuxt config file can be useful in case you'd like to override the built-in Vuetify styles, which was the case for me too (e.g., the `v-application` styles that come via `v-app` needed to be adjusted).